# Unauthorized issues when adding new kubernetes master

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I am trying to add new master , and I copy cert and keys i.e. **/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt** from current master to a new one. I noticed that after I do '**kubeadm init --config=config.yaml**' this key (probably all of them) is changing (*kubeadm init* itself is successful).. Why is this happening and could it be a root cause of my new master being in ***NotReady*** status ?

**systemctl status kubelet** shows a lot of *Failed to list *v1.Node: Unauthorized*, *Failed to list *v1.Secret: Unauthorized*..

```
docker@R90HE73F:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION

k8s-master-0 Ready master 7d1h v1.13.1

k8s-master-1 Ready master 7d v1.13.1

k8s-master-2 NotReady master 104m v1.13.1

k8s-worker-0 Ready <none> 7d v1.13.1

k8s-worker-1 Ready <none> 7d v1.13.1

k8s-worker-2 Ready <none> 7d v1.13.1
```

Btw etcd cluster is healthy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a new master to kubernetes cluster, you need to copy four files from your existing kubernetes master certificate directory before doing `kubeadm init` on new master. Those files are `ca.crt, ca.key, sa.pub, sa.key` and copy these files to `/etc/kubernetes/pki` folder on new master. If you don't copy the `sa*` files your kubernetes master will be into `NotReady` state and will have those errors.

For more information on how to setup kubernetes multi master, please check out my blog on kubernetes high availability:

https://velotio.com/blog/2018/6/15/kubernetes-high-availability-kubeadm

Comment: cool blog, appreciate , will follow your recommendation and get back